# How to fire multiple queries to MySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, web, mysqli

```
Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="../quiz.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<title>Administrator Approval</title>
</head>

<body>
<br><h2><div  class=head1>User Approval</div></h2>
<table width="75%" align="center" bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding="5px"border="1">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Select&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">User Id&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">Login&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">Password&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">Username&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">Address&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">City &nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">Phone&nbsp;</th>
    <th scope="col">Email&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
 <?php
 extract($_POST);
 $query=mysql_query('select * from approval');
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
 echo"<tr>";
 echo"<form action='approve.php' method='post'>";
 echo"<td align='center'><input type='checkbox' name='approve' value='$row[0]'> &nbsp</td>";
 echo"<td align='center'>$row[0] &nbsp;</td>
    <td align='center'>$row[1] &nbsp;</td>
    <td align='center'>$row[2] &nbsp;</td>
    <td align='center'>$row[3] &nbsp;</td>
    <td align='center'>$row[4] &nbsp;</td>
    <td align='center'>$row[5] &nbsp;</td>
    <td align='center'>$row[6] &nbsp;</td>
    <td align='center'>$row[7] &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>";
 }

echo"<td colspan='9' align='center'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Approve'></td>";
echo"</table>";
echo"</form>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The above (incomplete)file is for approval for student accounts by administrator.As you can see the selected entries from ***approval*** table are added in ***user*** table but the **user_id(i.e row[0])** can be multiple as I have provided checkboxes. I want to insert the(multiple) data of that user id to ***user*** table on a single "submit" Any Suggestions?

Comment: google: sql transactions

Comment: ftr: Don't use tables for anything else than tabular data! A form is not tabular data. It's semantically incorrect, you lose a lot of styling possibilities, etc. Besides your code/example has a lot of issues imho: `<form>` is open in a row but closed after `</table>`, `<form>` is opened *inside* the loop, `echo` to output HTML instead of opening/closing `<?php ?>`, using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, not sanitizing the input (SQL injection anyone?), XHTML1.1 doctype, …

Comment: +1 for being needlessly dogpiled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `name='approve'` to `name=approve[]`. Then in `approve.php` you can access it as an array:

```
foreach ($_POST['approve'] as $userid) {
    // Code to approve $userid
}
```